# pthread accessing it from a Class, variables are lost, when directly works fine

Tags: c++, pthreads

Well I'm trying to set a variable to use in a thread, it works fine if I call the pthread from the main function, but if I call it from a function or a function inside a class, the variable is lost and prints garbage instead, that's why I added the condition

> if(this->pickup < 7)

so I minimized the code so I could post it here because it has all the examples I'm saying.

The output of this code below is:

> Access by Class:
>
> Hello, world! <
>
> Access Directly:
>
> Hello, world!, N: 6<

I would like to have the same result as in Access Directly  in Access by Class, I want it to output the ", N: 6" because after all it was defined. what am I missing here?

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance.

(By the way, I'm using the pthread library that is available for windows)
so here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

class C {
public:
    int pickup;

    void *hello()
    {
        std::cout << "\nHello, world!";

        if(this->pickup < 7)
        std::cout << ", N: " << this->pickup;

        std::cout << "<" << std::endl;
        printf("HI");
        return 0;
    }

    static void *hello_helper(void *context)
    {
        return ((C *)context)->hello();
    }


    void StartThread(){
        C c;
        c.pickup = 6;

        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, &c);
    }


};



int main () {

    C c;
    std::cout << "Access by Class: \n";
    c.StartThread();
    c.pickup = 6;
    Sleep(2000);

    std::cout << "\nAccess Directly: \n";
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, &c);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is destroyed when `StartThread()` returns, meaning `hello_helper()` is using a dangling pointer resulting in undefined behaviour.

Change to:

```
void StartThread(){
    C* c = new C();
    c->pickup = 6;

    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, c);
}
```

Remember to `delete` the argument passed into `hello_helper()`:

```
static void *hello_helper(void *context)
{
    C* c = static_cast<C*>(context);
    c->hello();
    delete c;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Always `delete`ing the argument passed into `hello_helper()` would prevent passing stack allocated objects into `hello_helper()`. A mechanism is required to instruct `hello_helper()` whether it is responsible for destructing its argument.

Comment: it still printed garbage, it went  Hello, World!, N: -17891602

Comment: replace `printf()` with `std::cout`.

Comment: this worked but in the "access directly" part generated this error: "BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" in the runtime

Comment: That is due to `delete` of a stack allocated object (i.e. not `new`). You need some way to instruct the `hello_helper()` function to `delete` or not `delete` the object passed into it. If you remove the `delete` it would work but result in a memory leak.

Comment: Yeaa that's correct. I will use delete to avoid memory leak, and I really wanted to put the function in class, and you solved my doubt, so thank you. :)

Comment: Surely some kind of memory barrier is also required to do this safely, otherwise the second thread may never see the update from the first thread?

Comment: You are writing 6 to a memory location in one thread and hoping that when another thread reads that memory location it will see the value 6. This is in general not guarenteed unless you use a memory barrier to ensure that the cache memory between different cores synchronise properly. On a single core you'll be ok. On most Intel processors you'll probably be ok.  But in general you can't just update a variable in one thread and expect to see that update immediately in another thread. std::atomic in c++ helps to address this... (In practice it will likely work, but it's not guarenteed)

Answer (score 1):

The `C` you're starting the thread with in `StartThread()` goes out of scope and is destructed before the thread you are creating has a chance to use it.

If you know the class instance you're calling `StartThread()` on will exist for the life of the thread, perhaps you want to pass `this` as the context rather than a new stack object:

```
void StartThread() {
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, this);
}
```

Comment: hmm this I knew that worked , but I want to define the variable inside of the function instead of outside. Like I was doing C c;
  c.pickup = 6; inside of the StartThread

Comment: Then StartThread should be static. There's no reason to create a `C` in main just to call StartThread on it so it can create another `C` to start the thread on.

Comment: hmm I agree with you, I'm going with your style. it's good. thanks!

Comment: Do watch out for object lifetime though. Make sure your C object doesn't go out of scope and get deallocated before the thread is finished.

Comment: that's why I wanted to make a new object. :/ to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `pthread_create()` returns instantly, therefore you exit from the `C::StartThread` function before your spawned thread really has a chance to run.  Thus the `C` instance object represented by `c` doesn't exist anymore since it was an automatic variable on the stack of `StartThread`.  You need to make sure the life-time of `c` exists beyond the stack of `StartThread`, which is typically done using dynamic memory, or possibly a static variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `StartThread` creates a `C` object which is produced neither from any argument material (`StartThread` takes no arguments) nor from any member material of the classt of which `StartThread` is a member. I.e you can have this:

```
void StartThread(){
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, NULL);
}

// The code is easily moved into the thread.
static void hello_helper(void *)
{
   C c;
   c.pickup = 6;

}
```

Furthermore, is it possible that you actually wanted this?

```
void StartThread(){
    pthread_t t;
    pickup = 6;
    // use THIS object, not some new one, doh?
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, (void *) this);
}
```

I.e. maybe you actually want `obj.StartThread()` to start a thread which works with `obj` rather than creating some other object internally?